# Change memory ressource during job run

Tags: memory, reduce, slurm

Is it possible to change --mem-per-cpu value during the execution of a job ?

In my script I've a very memory consuming task (~50Gb) but with a very limited runtime (~30 min). After that several small memory-consuming tasks with long-runtimes (~12 hours) have to run. I've more than 300 similar jobs to submit using --array=1-300. So is it possible to reduce the required memory after the first memory-consuming task in order to allow other jobs to be submitted ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change the memory requirements of a running job. You should split your scripts in 2 and run the memory consuming task in on job and the smaller tasks in another job. You can set dependencies between jobs to ensure that the small jobs are run after the large job is completed.